# How can I take this working code and make it use java generics?

Tags: java, generics, jersey

I have a method without generics defined like this:

```
private void methodWithoutGenerics(Integer subjectKey) {
    Client client = AuthClient.create();
    List<JsonResult> clinicalItems = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + "results")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<List<JsonResult>>() {
            });

    assertFalse(clinicalItems.isEmpty());

    JsonResult clinicalItem = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + "results" + "/" + clinicalItems.get(0).getClinicalItemKey())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<JsonResult>() {
            });

    assertNotNull(clinicalItem);
}
```

This code is working, but I'd like to be able to call it with different types like this:

```
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "results", JsonResult.class);
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "medications", JsonMedication.class);
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "allergies", JsonAllergy.class);
```

And I can't figure out a way to generify the above method so that it "works" with this signature.  I'm worried I'll have to copy and paste the enter thing three times.

All of these classes on the right hand side have a base class named `JsonClinicalItem`.  It has the one method I call on the clinical item named `getClinicalItemKey()`.

How can I generify this?  Is it even possible?

---

Here's what I've attempted:

```
private <T extends JsonClinicalItem> void methodWithGenerics(Integer subjectKey, String pluralName, Class<T> t) {
    Client client = AuthClient.create();
    List<T> clinicalItems = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + pluralName)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<List<T>>() {
            });

    assertFalse(clinicalItems.isEmpty());

    T clinicalItem = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + pluralName + "/" + clinicalItems.get(0).getClinicalItemKey())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<T>() {
            });

    assertNotNull(clinicalItem);
}
```

This compiles, but when I run my code, the `methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "results", JsonResult.class);` throws a class cast exception.  So clearly there's some difference in the way I've written this generic method vs the way the original method looks.   That being said, I've compared the server output between the two calls and they are identical.  Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.TypeUtil.getTypes(TypeUtil.java:362)
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.TypeUtil.match(TypeUtil.java:298)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.provide(BasicConvertersFactory.java:102)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:74)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:56)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:58)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:22)
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.provideConverter(Genson.java:182)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$CollectionConverterFactory.create(DefaultConverters.java:115)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$CollectionConverterFactory.create(DefaultConverters.java:106)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.provide(BasicConvertersFactory.java:102)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:74)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:56)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:58)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:22)
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.provideConverter(Genson.java:182)
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:330)
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jersey.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:565)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:535)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:512)
    at com.mirth.results.rest.resource.UrlsWorkIntegrationTest.methodWithGenerics(UrlsWorkIntegrationTest.java:114)
    at com.mirth.results.rest.resource.UrlsWorkIntegrationTest.canTraverseUrls(UrlsWorkIntegrationTest.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

It's erroring on the line that says:

```
    List<T> clinicalItems = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + pluralName)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(new GenericType<List<T>>() {
            });
```

If I run my `methodWithoutGenerics`, this error doesn't occur.  So there must be some difference in the generics between the two that I don't understand.

This code is using Jersey.  I'm thinking that doesn't matter because my "withoutGenerics" method is working correctly so this probably isn't a Jersey issue.  But here are my dependencies on Jersey:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server-linking</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Um... Where is `t` used in the code?

Comment: You should probably just be passing in the object (vs the class).  I don't think this really needs to use generics, just inheritance.  Since all those objects extend `JsonClinicalItem` you can pass them in and treat them as `JsonClinicalItem` with no need for generics.  so you signature would be `methodWithGenerics(Integer subjectKey, String pluralName, JsonClinicalItem item)`

Comment: @ZiyaoWei It's not used in the code.  I couldn't figure any other way to set the `<T>` variable without having it as a parameter though

Comment: @Gus: I don't have an object instance.  I could create an empty one and pass it in if that would solve the problem.  But I still wouldn't know how to set the generics inside the method that currently say `JsonResult`

Comment: @rahulmaindargi The method already shows you how it's calling that.  I don't think my company would allow me to show you the JSON representation.  I'm not convinced that's relevant anyway.

Comment: Can you show what line is exactly... `UrlsWorkIntegrationTest.java:114` from `methodWithGenerics`?

Comment: @tieTYT check updated answer... some how `Class<T> t` is the only change you need in that method to be correct generics.. there si something different hapening on server in two calls its giving wrong json ..error is in parsing JSON... to collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenericType` works by looking at its own class declaration, getting the parameter of the generic supertype from its own class declaration. When you create an anonymous class like this `new GenericType<List<JsonResult>>() { }`, the supertype of that class is `GenericType<List<JsonResult>>` and this declaration information is stored in the bytecode and can be retrieved at runtime and it can get `List<JsonResult>` out of it.

This means that if you create an anonymous class like this `new GenericType<List<T>>() { }`, it gets literally `List<T>` out of this. Not `List<Something>`; just `List<T>`, because that is how the class is declared. Here `T` is just seen as some type parameter. In other words, for the subclassing trick of `GenericType` to work, the type information must be hard-coded at compile-time.

So what happens if your function must do this for one of many types? One solution, as you've found, is to have the caller pass in the appropriately-constructed `GenericType` object. The caller would presumably get it by using the subclass with a hard-coded type (presumably each calling place would only need to do this for one type, hence it can hard-code it).

The alternative is to actually construct the `GenericType` object yourself at runtime. The `com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType` class provides a second constructor, which takes a `Type` argument, which allows you to create a `GenericType` based on that type. `Type` represents any generic or non-generic type in Java. For a non-generic type, simply use the class object:

```
T clinicalItem = client
        .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + pluralName + "/" + clinicalItems.get(0).getClinicalItemKey())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .get(new GenericType<T>(t));
```

For a generic type, you have to make something that implements the `ParameterizedType` interface. You can implement your own class that does this, or take an existing implementation somewhere, but I'm gonna just show a simplified version:

```
List<T> clinicalItems = client
        .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + pluralName)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .get(new GenericType<List<T>>(new ParameterizedType() {
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() { return new Type[]{t}; }
            public Type getRawType() { return List.class; }
            public Type getOwnerType() { return null; }
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.  I don't really understand the difference between those last two samples.  Does the one that passes in `t` work as-is?  Why/when do I have to use the second one?  I can see one returns `T` and the other returns `List<T>`, but you didn't really explicitly point that out.  Perhaps when you said, "For a generic type" you meant to say, "For a List type"?

Comment: Also, just to be 100% complete, what should the `methodWithGenerics` method signature look like?

Comment: @tieTYT: I meant for it to be used with the code in your question, so `<T extends JsonClinicalItem> void methodWithGenerics(Integer subjectKey, String pluralName, Class<T> t)`

Comment: thanks, can you answer my other questions above that?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the method like this for class parameters

```
private <T extends JsonClinicalItem> void methodWithGenerics(
    Integer subjectKey, String pluralName, Class<T> t) {
```

This change is neccesary for sure...

`Illegal character at row 0 and column 763 expected [ but read ',' !`

shows that as you are expecting List/Array of elements the JSON representation should start with `[` but it finds `,`

something like

```
[ {PQR: "abc", abc: "lmn"}, {PQR: "abcd", abc: "lmnd"}]
```

if you can not show JSON representation to us i will suggest to try to print the JSON you Create on server side... and check how different it is from  first call `withoutGenerics` to second 'With Generics'

Comment: That gives me the same exception

Comment: ok, I shall try to compare the differences in the JSON generated

Comment: The client and the server are sending identical messages in both cases.  This is just a client side runtime issue.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks the get() method is using the GenericType's type parameter information while constructing itself, which is getting erased at runtime.

I have not worked with Jersey before.  But based on the API documentation one question and one suggestion:

- How are you able to instantiate the GenericType with the default constructor?  It seems to be protected as per the javadoc [here](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/GenericType.html#GenericType%28%29).
- You should try using the alternate constructor that is provided which takes a "Type" argument.

The standard java.lang.Class implements the java.lang.reflect.Type interface.  So I guess you just need to pass your Class argument as the Type instance.

Comment: added it to the stacktrace

Comment: added the dependency to the bottom of my question

Comment: I have a feeling you're on to something, but I can't figure out how to call that constructor.  `Type` is from `java.lang.reflect`, I'm not sure how to properly create an instance of it.

Comment: Did you try the other constructor?  Edited my post for more clarity on the type parameter.

Comment: Yes, I can get the other constructor to compile, but it's a challenge to figure out how to pass it into the `get` method and have it return a `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

To fix my problem, I changed the signature of my method slightly so now I call it like this:

```
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "results", new GenericType<List<JsonResult>>() {}, new GenericType<JsonResult>() {});
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "medications", new GenericType<List<JsonMedication>>() {}, new GenericType<JsonMedication>() {});
    methodWithGenerics(subjectKey, "allergies", new GenericType<List<JsonClinicalItem>>() {}, new GenericType<JsonClinicalItem>() {});
```

And now my method looks like this:

```
private <T extends JsonClinicalItem> void methodWithGenerics(Integer subjectKey, String plural, GenericType<List<T>> listType, GenericType<T> resultType) {
    Client client = AuthClient.create();
    List<T> clinicalItems = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + plural)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(listType);

    assertFalse(clinicalItems.isEmpty());

    T clinicalItem = client
            .resource(getBaseUrl() + "/rest/v1/patients/" + subjectKey + "/" + plural + "/" + clinicalItems.get(0).getClinicalItemKey())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(resultType);

    assertNotNull(clinicalItem);
}
```

I'm not sure why this makes any difference compared to all the suggestions people were helping me with, but this compiles and runs without error.  None of the other suggestions worked for me even though they were good ideas.